# Excel 365: COUNTIFS with range as a criteria to lookup

Tags: excel

[as per the comments, I am happy to provide a minimal example of the problem if someone can tell me how to upload excel to stack overflow!]

I had a look at previous answers, but nothing seems to fit.  Once answer nearly did, but I can't adapt it.  Trying to steer clear of VBA but please tell me if needs must.

Basically, I have a large-ish sheet of incident tickets.  Some are logged by company A, and some by company B.  Unfortunately, the only way to tell which company has logged which ticket is to search in another table on name.  What I am trying to do is count tickets that match certain criteria that were logged by, let's say, company B - I have the list of people at company B in a worksheet in the workbook

Obviously, COUNTIFS seems to be the obvious answer, except I can't seem to get a sensible answer from COUNTIFS.  :)  So, I can get a perfect number of tickets for this or that criterion, but I am unable to add that the ticket should be from company B only, ie: I need a COUNTIFS('Ticket'!$D:$D,'CoBPeople'!$N:$N) term, and I don't see how that's possible to include.  In VB, I would know which thing I am iterating over and check each time (inefficient, I know, but we're talking thousands here, not millions!) and just add them up, but it doesn't seem to be possible to get COUNTIFS to "lookup" each name it finds as it does its thing.

Any ideas?  I just feels like there is an obvious answer I am missing...

Thanks in advance!
MrBB.

Comment: So add a column that checks which company a person works at. Then just use that result, unless you don’t have any columns left…

Comment: A small example dataset together with expected results would be useful.

Comment: You can't nest a Vlookup or Countif inside a Countifs in any useful way, so if you didn't want to add another column for some reason you would need to consider a Sumproduct formula.

Comment: Agreed, provide some example data, makes it easier to work with.

Comment: If someone can tell me how to put an example on here, happy to provide it.  There doesn't seem to be a way to upload and example workbook, so...

Comment: Thanks all.  I was hoping to be able to do tis without modifying the ticket dump, but adding a column that checks which company a person works for does look like that's the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to be able to do tis without modifying the ticket dump, but adding a column that checks which company a person works for does look like that's the easiest solution.